# Volume Testing Using Selenium

Tags: selenium

Issue: A code change to how our Instagram feed works on the Y page resulted in a memory overflow under production traffic volume, that did not occur in lower (QA / Preview) traffic volume. When the overflow occurred, an AEM bug was triggered that wrote data to large files on the disk. These files grew to exceed disk capacity.

It was identified as disk space to be the problem. Hence, expanded it and sent it and later disk space exceeded again. Disk space was expanded again to fix the incident.

Query:

1. How good is Selenium at rapidly executing a script? The thought is, can this kind of issue be tested using selenium?
2. Can 'Volume Testing' be performed using Selenium?

Comment: Related: http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/5389/looking-for-open-source-java-based-tool-for-performance-testing/5390#5390

Answer (score 2):

No , you can not do performance testing using selenium. Selenium is for functionality testing.

For performance testing please use : [Jmeter for load testing](http://jmeter.apache.org/)

Comment: You could use Selenium but it's not recommended and there are much more suitable tools

Comment: Can you please elaborate on which tool would be more suitable for Volume testing with respect to the above scenario?

Comment: As I told in answer , you can use Jmeter.